# How to remove a large number of rows from Excel spreadsheet based on time?

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with over 44,000 rows (sensor readings taken each minute for a month). I want to reduce them to every 15 minutes.

[image]

I want to remove rows where `Time` -column does not end in :

```
01
16
31
46
```

Comment: your question is complicated. for 2 hours I'm trying to understand what you need

Answer (score 0):

We can do something using two main figures:

1. `openpyxl` package to retrieve the data from the **Excel sheet**.

`pip3 install openpyxl`

2. `String Operation` to compare the value if its == 15 minutes:
3. Insert into a list.
4. If you want to appened it into the Excel sheet, again. Please, check this reference [writing into Excel using openpyxl](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-writing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/?ref=rp)

```
# importing openpyxl module 
import openpyxl 
  
# Give the location of the file 
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx"
  
# workbook object is created 
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 
  
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active 
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row 
aList = []
# Loop will print all values 
# of first column  
for i in range(2, m_row + 1): 
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1) 
    if (cell_obj.value[:-2] == 15):
        aList.append(cell_obj.value)
```

For more information about `openpyxl`, please check this hyperlink;

[**How to read from Excel sheet using openpyxl**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find a solution using Python, so this is no longer an issue.  Thank you.

data2 = data.set_index('Time').resample('15T').mean()

data2

Comment: at least, show us the solution or delete the post!!!